# How does boundary perturbation affect the eigenvalues of differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues, sturm-liouville-theory

There is a well-known procedure (at least to me) to compute how a small perturbation will affect the eigenvalues of a differential equation.

However, the method deals only with perturbing the differential operator itself - but there is another important ingredient in the problem, the boundary conditions. This leads me to the question: Can we compute the approximate eigenvalues to the problem if we slightly perturb the boundary?

As an example of what I have in mind, consider the 1D S-L problem $u''=\lambda u$ with the BCs $u(0)=0$and $u(L)=0$. This arises naturally from the 1D wave equation.

The eigenvalues for this problem are $\lambda_n = \frac {n^2 \pi^2} {L^2}$. If we change the boundary to be the points $0$ and $L+\varepsilon$, the new eigenvalues are then given by $\lambda'_n = \frac {n^2 \pi^2} {(L+\varepsilon)^2} \approx \frac {n^2 \pi^2} {L^2} - \frac {2n^2 \pi^2} {L^3} \varepsilon$. Could we evaluate this without solving for the eigenvalues in the first place (which is not possible for harder problems)?

But the case I'm interested in the most is perturbation of the boundary in 2D and 3D problems, such as $\nabla^2 u=u_{tt}$. If the boundary is a rectangle, we can solve in Cartesian coordinates by separation of variables. If it is a perturbed rectangle, we could probably make a change of coordinates, separate the equation and solve accordingly... But this method seems to be very cumbersome, especially for more complicated boundaries. Is there an easier way?

Comment: The usual way to handle perturbed boundaries is, as you say, a change of coordinates that maps the problem back to the original domain. For S-L problems, this is easy. In higher dimensions, it inevitably leads to nonconstant coefficients, and you can no longer separate variables. However, if the perturbation involves a small parameter, you can get a series expansion for your solution.